# Cannot get translated value for an entity inside twig

Tags: 8

Inside a custom module I get the translated nodes like this:

```
$ids = Drupal::entityQuery('node')
    ->condition('type', 'event')
    ->condition('status', 1)
    ->execute();

$nodes = Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadMultiple($ids);

$events = array_map(function ($node) {
    return Drupal::entityManager()->getTranslationFromContext($node);
}, $nodes);
```

and inside the template:

```
<div class="events">
  {% for event in events %}
    <div>
      <h4>{{ event.title.value }}</h4>
      <div class="event-type">
        {{ event.field_event_type.entity.name.value }}
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

The event_type entity which is a taxonomy is displayed in the original language always. How can I get the translated value for the entity too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to prepare the taxonomy entities the same way like the nodes. But normally it's not your job to do either of this.

Use [viewMultiple()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityViewBuilder.php/function/EntityViewBuilder%3A%3AviewMultiple/8.4.x) instead of array_map() in the first php example:

```
$nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadMultiple($ids);
$build = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('node')->viewMultiple($nodes, $view_mode);
$variables['events'] = $build;
```

In Twig:

```
{{ events }}
```

Customize the twig of the view mode specific event content type and other templates like the taxonomy field template if needed.